# How to manipulate my object containing array of object

Tags: arrays, json, angular, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I'm getting this info from API.

```
{
   _id:number
   option1:[{name:{fr:string,en:string},price:number}],
   option2:[{name:{fr:string,en:string},price:number}]
}
```

and I want to transform the name field to return only the proper language value (FR or EN / locale).

```
{
   option1:[{name:string,price:number},
   option2:[{name:string,price:number}
}
```

What I tried so far but doesn't work

```
return this.http.get<Options>(optionsUrl).pipe(
  map(obj=>({
    ...obj,
    option1: obj.option1.map(obj=>({
      ...obj,
      name: obj.name[locale]
    }),
    option2: obj.option2.map(obj=>({
      ...obj,
      name: obj.name[locale]
    }),
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue.
It was related to the Options interface. It works if I put any

```
return this.http.get<any>(optionsUrl).pipe(
 map(obj=>({
  ...obj,
  option1: obj.option1.map(obj=>({
     ...obj,
     name: obj.name[locale]
  }),
  option2: obj.option2.map(obj=>({
     ...obj,
     name: obj.name[locale]
  }),
}))
```